# C - How to count occurrences of each word in a file and remove duplicate words

Tags: c, struct, fgets

My current assignment in university is to read in words from a file and count the occurrences of each word in that file, printing my results to the console/new file.

I have been successful in counting the word occurrences, however, I am having difficulty removing the rest of the values.

E.g. I want to remove the additional occurrences of C, but keep its count.

`C : 2
they : 2
are : 1
not : 1
they : 2
written : 1
in : 1
C : 2`

Here is the code I have at the moment...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 256

struct words
{
    char *word;
    unsigned int count;
};

int count_words()
{
    // Allocate memory for first word to compare + words struct
    char *key_word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZE);
    struct words *w = (struct words*)malloc(sizeof(struct words) * SIZE);
    // Create variable to read words from file
    FILE *word_list = fopen("single_words_test.txt", "r");
    // Variable to store total word count
    int total_words = 0;

    // Read in words from file line by line
    while (fgets(key_word, SIZE, word_list) != NULL)
    {
        // Remove the newline character
        key_word[strlen(key_word) - 1] = '\0';
        // Initialize members of words structure
        w->word = key_word;
        w->count = 0;
        // Allocate memory for current word being compared to key_word
        char *current_word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZE);
        // Create variable to read second list of words from file
        FILE *word_list2 = fopen("single_words_test.txt", "r");

        while (fgets(current_word, SIZE, word_list2) != NULL)
        {
            // Remove newline character
            current_word[strlen(current_word) - 1] = '\0';
            // If currrent read word matches keyword, increase its count
            if (strcmp(key_word, current_word) == 0)
            {
                w->count++;
            }
        }
        // Free the allocated memory
        free(current_word);
        fclose(word_list2);

        total_words++;

        printf("%s : %d\n", w->word, w->count);
    }

    free(w);
    free(key_word);
    fclose(word_list);

    return total_words;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    printf("\n\n\n%d\n\n\n", count_words());

    return 0;

}
```

I know the code is messy but I have been stuck on this for some time and I am unsure of how to implement it into my current solution.

Also, I know this could be done by creating a linked-list but I want to avoid that solution and keep it similar to the current solution.

Thank you and sorry for the ambiguity of the question

EDIT: This isn't a code request. I would just like some general guidance as to what I could use

Comment: what do you mean by "I am having difficulty removing the rest of the values"

Comment: @Dinesh If the word "Hello" is counted twice in the file, I want my console to only print "Hello" once and not the number of times it was counted

Comment: maintain a map with words and count. if the word already exists increase the count, else insert into the map with count 1.
And while printing print the word and the count from the map.

Comment: "keep it similar to the current solution." leads to the same problem.  Rather than re-read the file, compare string against the list  read so far and only add new words to the list.  Replace `w->word = key_word;` with `w->word = strdup(key_word);`

Comment: @chux I have tried using an additional for loop and strcmp() but nothing has worked so I just removed the code again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if you found the `current_word` earlier in the list than the `key_word` you're looking for.  You can do this using `ftell(...)` on the file pointer.

Here's an example;

```
int count_words()
{
    // Allocate memory for first word to compare + words struct
    char *key_word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZE);
    struct words *w = (struct words*)malloc(sizeof(struct words) * SIZE);
    // Create variable to read words from file
    FILE *word_list = fopen("single_words_test.txt", "r");
    // Variable to store total word count
    int total_words = 0;
    long word_list_pos, word_list2_pos;


    // Read in words from file line by line
    while (fgets(key_word, SIZE, word_list) != NULL)
    {
        // Remove the newline character
        key_word[strlen(key_word) - 1] = '\0';
        // Initialize members of words structure
        w->word = strdup(key_word);
        w->count = 0;
        word_list_pos = ftell(word_list);

        // Allocate memory for current word being compared to key_word
        char *current_word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZE);
        // Create variable to read second list of words from file
        FILE *word_list2 = fopen("single_words_test.txt", "r");

        while (fgets(current_word, SIZE, word_list2) != NULL)
        {
            // Remove newline character
            current_word[strlen(current_word) - 1] = '\0';
            // If currrent read word matches keyword, increase its count
            if (strcmp(key_word, current_word) == 0)
            {
                word_list2_pos = ftell(word_list2);                
                if (word_list2_pos < word_list_pos)
                    break;

                w->count++;
            }
        }
        total_words++;

        if (word_list2_pos >= word_list_pos)
            printf("%s : %d\n", w->word, w->count);

        // Free the allocated memory
        free(w->word);
        free(current_word);
        fclose(word_list2);

    }

    free(w);
    free(key_word);
    fclose(word_list);

    return total_words;
}
```